# mingw std::thread with Windows API

Tags: windows, c++11, mingw, stdthread

I started to use C++11 `std::thread` (mingw 4.8) so far so good. I ran into a situation with overlapped I/O where `sleepEx` was used to put the thread in an alertable wait state. This worked quite well, until `QueueUserAPC` had to be used, which returned an "invalid handle error".

After some searching found out that `std::thread` uses the pthread library under Windows.

Is there any way to use windows API calls which expect a thread handle with `std::thread` ?
Or do I need to stick with Windows threads for overlapped I/O ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows API, but it sounds like you are mixing Windows API threading with C++11 std::threads, and since mingw 4.8 uses pthreads under the hood, this is leading to problems. Is this correct? It's probably best to use only one threading API even if there was a way to get mingw std::threads to use Windows API threads instead of pthreads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to use windows API calls which expect a thread handle with std::thread ?

<strike>No, because the `std::thread` in your MinGW build isn't implemented in terms of thread handles.</strike> **Edit:** it is, but indirectly, see rubenvb's answer for how to get the native thread handle from a `pthread_t`, and you should be able to use `std::thread::native_handle()` to get the `pthread_t`.

Noone has implemented the necessary support in GCC for the C++11 thread library to use native Windows threads directly.

I had some [ideas](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-05/msg00020.html) for a new thead model that would be implemented in terms of native mutexes and condition variables.  That would allow you to call `std::thread::native_handle()` to get the underlying thread handle to use with the Windows API.

I got as far as rebuilding GCC with my changes applied, but couldn't test them. There was almost no interest in my suggestions and no offers to help from any MinGW contributors, so as I'm not a Windows user, and working on Windows and building MinGW was so painful and frustrating, I gave up.  I should put my changes online somewhere, so that someone with more patience than me can finish the work one day.

Comment: I followed your discussion with K. Frank who is active on the MinGW-w64 mailing list. He implemented Vista+-only gthread wrapper code making std::thread available on Win32 native primitives. As you said, this is unacceptable without a new threading model to allow for XP-compatible toolchains. I know this is a bad place to have this discussion, but could a runtime choice between two implementations (one slow for XP, another fast for newer versions)? I'm sure there's some `dload`s somewhere in GCC, why not for this?

Comment: Hi Ruben, glad to here there's some interest in it. It's not currently possible to choose at run-time, because the gthread wrappers are either inline functions or compiled into libgcc, and the code that gets used is chosen when configuring GCC. In theory I suppose a new Vista+ gthread model could have libgcc call into some other DLL, and there could be alternative implementations of that DLL. It would require quite a lot of changes, but I'd be willing to help get that into GCC (probably not before February/March next year though)

Answer (score 5):

To solve your issue, MinGW-w64 winpthreads (the pthreads implementation you are using), just like [pthreads-win32](http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/), allows you to get the native Win32 thread handle for a pthread:

```
void * pthread_gethandle (pthread_t t);
```

Note that this is currently an undocumented function.

The corresponding function in pthreads-win32 is:

```
HANDLE pthread_getw32threadhandle_np(pthread_t thread);
```

I'd bet this will make your intermixing of the two work, or at least bring to light some bugs in winpthreads which can be fixed. In the latter case, please report them to MinGW-w64.

If the above returns an invalid handle, your best bet is to ask on the MinGW-w64-public mailing list (subscribe first, otherwise you'll have to wait for manual moderation which is silly).

Comment: Nice, combining that function with `std::thread::native_handle()` might work then.

Comment: The pthread.h included with GCC4.8 does not include pthread_getw32threadhandle_np unfortunately.

Comment: @Waldorf OK. It seems I found a pthreads-win32 test file inside the winpthreads source tree using it. How about [pthread_gethandle](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/HEAD/tree/stable/v3.x/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads/include/pthread.h#l404) which seems to [return a `HANDLE`](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/HEAD/tree/stable/v3.x/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads/src/thread.h#l42). Note that this function is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks! Although it seems an undocumented function it works as expected. When passing the native_handle it returns a valid windows thread handle and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a native win32 implementation of std::thread and sync primitives, see:

https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads

This is a header-only library and works with any version of MinGW that has proper language support for C++11